# HtmlEditor causes unwanted breaklines

Tags: asp.net, css, listview, html-editor

I am not using the AjaxControlToolkit's HtmlEditor because it do not have a direct button to insert images, that is why I searched for another editor and I finally found the [Winthusiasm](http://www.winthusiasm.com/Articles/HtmlEditor/HtmlEditor.aspx) editor.

Everything seems to work fine, but it really doesn't. Let's see that step by step. In the example I am demonstrating the use of a subscript, but the behavior is the same for any improvement of the text (bold, italic, ...):

**1** - I use the HtmlEditor to insert enhanced text into the database. I have developed a page that works as ControlPanel and this page shows the existing items stored in the database as a `ListView`:

[image: ListView preview]

**2** - If I click on "edit" button I can edit the content by the HtmlEditor:

[image: HtmlEditor preview]

**3** - So far so good. The issue occurs on the end-user page, the page in which the content is going to be showed for all the regular users of the page:

[image: End-user page preview]

I researched on the generated source code in this last page but I can not find any `br` declared. Everything seems ok in the code, so I am completely lost. I tried to enter the text in an `ASP:Literal` and an `ASP:Label`, but the result is the same.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I figured out it was just a CSS issue because although Chrome shows the text in a wrong way, Internet Explorer was rendering it fine, so it could not be a code issue.